# Windows Application crashes due to CLR.dll - Windows 2008 R2 Server

Tags: c#, .net, windows, crash, clr

I have a Dot Net Framework 4.0 based application developed on Visual Studio 2010 Professional which is running as a Windows Service on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Version with Service Pack 1, 64 bit Operating System.
The application seems to crash intermittently and the reason is as below :

> Faulting Module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.1026
>
> Exception Code: 0xc0000409
>
> Fault Offset: 0x002b79d8
>
> Faulting module path: C:\Widows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll

Can you kindly let me know if there is any HOTFIX for this CLR.dll crash issue? If yes can you let me know regarding the same?

Answer (score 0):

Install this [HOTFIX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2640103) from windows.

Comment: I don't think this will be helpful, his build of clr.dll (1026) should include this fix already.